# XmlElement convert open tag to string c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert to string a subset of OuterXml content of a XmlElement as in the following example.

Imagine I have an XmlElement object representing the some-element tag

```
<some-element attribute="value">
    <inner-element>
        text content
    </inner-element>
</some-element>
```

What's the best approach to get a string that is just `<some-element attribute="value">`?

If possible, I'd prefer a solution without regular expressions involved, but using DOM classes

Comment: you're probably not going to get any help unless you demonstrate what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by creating a *temporary* XElement instead using LINQ

```
IEnumerable<XAttribute> attributes = (from XmlAttribute xmlAttribute in node.Attributes select new XAttribute(xmlAttribute.Name, xmlAttribute.Value));

var xElement = new XElement(node.Name, attributes);

return xElement.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full XML of the element(which includes the close tag) by shallow cloning the node and then grabbing the outer XML of the node:

```
var xml = @"<some-element attribute=""value"">
     <inner-element>
         text content
      </inner-element>
    </some-element>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

MessageBox.Show(doc.DocumentElement.CloneNode(false).OuterXml);
```

I think after that point you will have to do some string manipulation to get exactly what you want, but that is relatively easy:

```
var outer = doc.DocumentElement.CloneNode(false).OuterXml;
var final = outer.Substring(0, outer.LastIndexOf(">", outer.Length - 2)+1);

MessageBox.Show(final);
```

Comment: Thanks John! That was useful, but I was trying to avoid string manipulation.